# Can i start .Net Console Application under custom user?

Tags: .net

I have a console application that i would like to run as 'MySpecificUser'. Can i specify this user in app.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. By the time the config file is read by the CLR it is too late to specify the user the process runs under. On the other hand you could write a launcher console application in whose config file you specify a username and password which are used to run the actual application using for example this [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx) overload.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) utility in order to execute *any* program as a specific user.

This is not something you could specify in a config, however, not directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible by editing the app.config.

You should rather use Process.Start in order to run the process under another user. You will need to provide a password for the user account otherwise it will not work.